# How to store a value from JSON response in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

This is my JSON Response of my Rest API.

```
{"ListClientResponse": {
   "Header": {"CMMHeader": {"CorrelationId": "cmm:CorrelationId"}},
   "Result":    {
      "ResponseCode": "CM-N-0000",
      "ResponseMessage": "No errors and warnings."
   },
   "ListClient": {"Client":    [
            {
         "OrganizationId": 523,
         "OrganizationName": "OrgX1518521.com",
         "OrganizationDomain": "X1518521.com"

            ],
            "RoleId": "AdminRole",
            "RoleName": "Admin"
         }
      },
```

I want to save **Organization Id** and **OrganizationDomain** from my JSON Response in a variables or something so that I can use these values later in my all JSON requests.

This is my JSON request.

```
var myCreateUserRequest =  {
                "CreateUserRequest": {
                       "Header": {
                        "CMMHeader": {
                            "CorrelationId": 5454354}},
                       "ClientContext":    {
                          "OrganizationId": **theOrgId,**
                          "OrganizationDomain": **theDomain,**
                       },
                       "User":    {
                          "UserName": aUser.Username,
                          "UserPassword": aUser.Password,
                          "UserStatus": "Active",

                          "RoleId": "Member"
                       }
                    }
                }
```

In my JSON request, inside the field of **OrganizationId** and **OrganizationDomain**  I want to pass that organizationID value and OrganizationDomain value that I have saved from my JSON **Response** in a varibale.  I want to save it in a way so that organizationId and OrganizationDomain can be accessible in my whole **ANGULAR JS** project and I can pass it in my any JSON request. How can I do that. Please tell me any suggestion.

Comment: use some storage methods like $localstorage,Session storage things to store those after the response and use them in making calls....and make sure when ever posting some json the opening and closings should be in correct way

Comment: @Sa E Chowdary It will be running on server later and different browser will access it. I cannot user local storage.

Comment: Hard to figure out what you are even asking

Comment: @charlietfl I want to save value of organizationID from JSON response and that value I want to later send in my JSON request. SIMPLE!

Comment: so storing in a service is simple too....not sure where your problem is. Then later when you need it you inject the service and get it doing something like `myService.ListClientResponse.ListClient.Client[0].OrganizationId`

Comment: @charlietfl  correct me if I am wrong, like -> var myCreateUserRequest =  {
                "CreateUserRequest": {
                       "Header": {
                        "CMMHeader": {
                            "CorrelationId": 5454354}},
                       "ClientContext":    {
                          "OrganizationId": UserService.ListClientResponse.ListClient.Client[0].Organizati‌​onId,
                          "OrganizationDomain": "domain503.com",
                       },

Comment: what is myService?

Comment: it's the angular service you use to store this object in. Probably same service you make request from

Comment: No they are two different service.

Answer (score 1):

Best practice in this case tells to create a [service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services). Becouse services are singleton in Angular, you can set a vale and inject in yours services/controllers and have access to the value.

Comment: Yes I am creating a service and my response JSON is actually the response of my service. Now I am calling a http post operation in which I want to send JSON and inside that JSON I want to send value of organizationID that i recieved from my response but how can I store and send it in all JSON requests? How can I set value?

Comment: There is an example https://jsfiddle.net/u5ffkd6q/ . If your second request it's immediately after the first, then you can make a chain of promise.

Comment: Thanks @Giorgio Cerruti but they are two different services and its not working.

Comment: **Describe the problem.** "It doesn't work" is not a problem statement. Tell us what the expected behavior should be. Tell us what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it.